# SED replace with 'dynamic variable' build from backreference

Tags: bash, sed

**UPDATED**

Let's say I have a file with this contents

```
database_driver="pdo_mysql"
database_host="11.22.33.44"
database_port="3306"


%database_driver%
%database_host%
%database_port%
```

Now I'd like to replace %database*****%  with the content of th corresponding variable, so i would end up with

```
pdo_mysql
11.22.33.44
3306
```

I now how to do this line by line, but I'd like to have one sed replace command to replace all values at once

I tried this

```
sed -r  "s/%(database.*)%/$\1/g" file.yml
```

I'm trying to create a variable from the second backreference, but this doesn't work, it get this

```
$database_driver
```

So I get the name of the variable, not the value

Any ideas?

**UPDATE**
I've got a number of answers but none of them seem to work and they all look very difficult.
I'd still like to have an answer to my initial question:  Is there a way to make this work

```
sed -r  "s/%(database.*)%/$\1/g" file.yml
```

This replaces

```
%SOMETHING%  into $SOMETHING
```

and

```
%SOMETHING_ELSE%  into $SOMETHING_ELSE.
```

But I need the VALUE of $SOMETHING and $SOMETHING_ELSE
This would be the most ideal solution I guess. Much shorter and more readable the the proposed solutions

Comment: Do you still want to keep the other lines ?

Comment: You can also `source a.txt` and then replace you have `$database_driver` available : )

Comment: I want al the placeholders ( % % ) to be replaced with the corresponding variable values  in 1 command if possible.

Comment: Difficult in sed (especially if you don't know what variables will appear in advance), easier in Perl. Does it have to be sed?

Comment: @Wintermute It's not that difficult in sed, i think my updated answer is quite easy to understand.

Comment: @User112638726 It only works for cases when variables have the whole line to themselves, though. Given that OP is working on YAML files, that strikes me as a bold assumption. It's possible to extend the approach with loops and more backrefs, but at that point I'd consider other tools that can do the job in a more straightforward manner.

Comment: @Wintermute It wouldn 't require any extra brackets, i could just match on the %% instead of the newlines.

Comment: I've got a number of answers but none of them seem to work and they all look very diffecult.
I'd still like to have an answer to my initial question:  Is there a way to make this work

sed -r  "s/%(database.*)%/$\1/g" file.yml

This replaces %SOMETHING%  into $SOMETHING and   %SOMETHING_ELSE%  into $SOMETHING_ELSE.

But i need the VALUE of $SOMETHING and $SOMETHING_ELSE
This would be the most ideal solution i guess. Much shorter and more readable the the proposed solutions

Comment: When you say `$SOMETHING`, do you mean environment variables? In the question sounds as though the variables were defined in the file, but the `$` makes no sense then. I'm not sure I understand what you mean anymore.

Comment: The variables are defined in the file like SOMETHING="mystring"
To use that variable if would call it $SOMETHING in bash, or......

Answer (score 1):

I would use `awk`, like this:

```
awk -F'"| +' '$1=="database_driver="{d=$2}/%database_driver%/{$2=d}1' a.txt
```

With the help of GNU `grep` you might even use this:

```
driver=$(grep -oP 'driver="\K[^"]+' a.txt)
sed "s/%database_driver%/$driver/" a.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

All in sed lol

```
sed '/^database.*=/{p;s/\(database[^=]*\)/%\1%/;H;d};/^%database/{G;s/^\([^\n]*\).*\1="\([^"]*\).*/\2/}' file
```

Basically it saves the lines you want values from and then replaces the line you want to replace with the value it saved.

Will work with generic data as it is matched later on.

#### Output

```
database_driver="pdo_mysql"
database_host="11.22.33.44"
database_port="3306"


pdo_mysql
11.22.33.44
3306
```

As mentioned by hek2mgl you can also put it in a script file

```
 /^database.*=/{p;s/\(database[^=]*\)/%\1%/;H;d}
 /^%database/{G;s/^\([^\n]*\).*\1="\([^"]*\).*/\2/}
```

Run as

```
sed -f "sedscript" file
```

Comment: I changed the orginal question. I deleted the driver: host: and port:  pieces, because they're not important.

Comment: Interesting solution! I suggest to make a multiline script out of it. This way you could use proper indenting and add nice comments to the script this way.

Comment: You asked how to make multiline script out of it: Simply put it into a file. Instead of `;` you put a newline. Then execute it using `sed -f scriptname`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ sed -f <(sed  '/^$/ q; s/\([^=]*\)="\([^"]*\)"/s|%\1%|\2|;/' file) file
```

#### file

```
database_driver="pdo_mysql"
database_host="11.22.33.44"
database_port="3306"


%database_driver%
%database_host%
%database_port%
```

#### Output

```
database_driver="pdo_mysql"
database_host="11.22.33.44"
database_port="3306"


pdo_mysql
11.22.33.44
3306
```

### Explanation:

```
sed  '/^$/ q; s/\([^=]*\)="\([^"]*\)"/s|%\1%|\2|;/'
```

Creates command input for the outer `sed`. It stops at an empty line and until then, converts assignment expressions to expressions such as:

```
s|%database_driver%|pdo_mysql|;
s|%database_host%|11.22.33.44|;
s|%database_port%|3306|;
```

This makes `"` behave like `'` does in bash (no escape sequences or interpolation with these double quotes) and assumes that nothing in between % is a character that's special to `sed` (you can ensure that by replacing `[^=]` with a range of allowed characters such as `[_0-9a-zA-Z]`).

---

**Note**: You might want to write the template in a proper templating langueage such as ERB or Handlerbars instead of doing this.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use Perl. This is much easier in Perl than it is in sed. For example:

```
perl -pe 's/%([^%]*)%/$vars{$1}/eg; if (/(\w+)="(.*)"/) { $vars{$1} = $2; }' filename
```

More readably:

```
s/%(\w+)%/$vars{$1}/eg;     # replace %%-encased words with the remembered value
                            # for the encased word

if (/(\w+)="(.*)"/) {       # When finding an assignment
  $vars{$1} = $2;           # remember the assigned value.
}
```

This approach will even let you use variables in variable assignments, which is to say that the input

```
database_driver="pdo_mysql"
database_host="11.22.33.44"
database_port="3306"
database_connstr="mysql:host=%database_host%;port=%database_port%"

%database_driver%
%database_host%
%database_port%
%database_connstr%
```

produces

```
database_driver="pdo_mysql"
database_host="11.22.33.44"
database_port="3306"
database_connstr="mysql:host=11.22.33.44;port=3306"

pdo_mysql
11.22.33.44
3306
mysql:host=11.22.33.44;port=3306
```

Answer (score 1):

This `sed` command will do:

```
sed -nr 's#database_([^"]*)="([^"]*)"#s/(\1:\\s*)%[^%]*%/\\1\2/#p' file| sed -r -f- file
```

### Explanation:

```
sed -nr 's#database_([^"]*)="([^"]*)"#s/(\1:\\s*)%[^%]*%/\\1\2/#p' file
```

generates an output:

```
s/(driver:\s*)%[^%]*%/\1pdo_mysql/
s/(host:\s*)%[^%]*%/\111.22.33.44/
s/(port:\s*)%[^%]*%/\13306/
```

which is then used as a `sed` script for the next `sed` after the pipe.

### UPDATE:

For your new file, it will be:

```
sed -nr 's#database_([^"]*)="([^"]*)"#s/%[^%]*\1%/\2/#p' file | sed -r -f- file
```

Answer (score 0):

Sed is for simple substitutions on individual lines, that's all. Just use awk:

```
$ awk -F'[="%]' 'NF==4{map[$1]=$3;next} NF{print map[$2]}' file
pdo_mysql
11.22.33.44
3306
```